# How to delete all lines containing fewer than two /'s in BASH?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

How can I delete all lines from a file containing only one or no `/`? E.g., `file.txt`:

```
This / line contains/ more than / one of the characters/.
This / line contains just one.
This / line/ also has/too many/.
```

The output would be:

```
This / line contains/ more than / one of the characters/.
This / line/ also has/too many/.
```

I tried `grep ^[^/]*/*[^/]$ file.txt`, but this seems to print everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You weren't too far away:

```
grep '/.*/' <<.eof
This / line contains/ more than / one of the characters/.
This / line contains just one.
This / line/ also has/too many/.
.eof
```

Results in:

```
This / line contains/ more than / one of the characters/.
This / line/ also has/too many/.
```

But I also like Kent's solution :-)

Comment: it doesn't actually delete anything from the file, just shows proper output, am i wrong?

Comment: @SandyElms That's true. I assume it's a mistake in the question since output example and `grep` call don't look like there's an intention of modifying the file

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
awk -F/ 'NF>2' file
```

test:

```
kent$ (master|✔) echo "This / line contains/ more than / one of the characters/.
dquote> This / line contains just one.
dquote> This / line/ also has/too many/."|awk -F/ 'NF>2'
This / line contains/ more than / one of the characters/.
This / line/ also has/too many/.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "This / line contains/ more than / one of the characters/.
This / line contains just one.
This / line/ also has/too many/." \
| sed -n '\@/.*/@p'
```

output

```
This / line contains/ more than / one of the characters/.
This / line/ also has/too many/.
```

The `-n` says "don't print by default. The regex in `sed` looks for lines with more than one `/` char and prints them.

Sed, being the variable tool that it is, may not like the leading `\` char in `\@`, so if you get an error message, just use `sed '@/.*@d'`

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

```
perl -ne '
 chomp;
 if ( ( $n1 = () = $_ =~ /\//g) > 1 ) { 
    print "$_\n";
 }' afile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk` version:

```
awk 'gsub(/\//,"&")>1' file
This / line contains/ more than / one of the characters/.
This / line/ also has/too many/.
```

It tries to swap `/` with itself.  The output of `gsub` is the number of hits.